# How do you keep unison from syncing large files?

Tags: large-files, unison

I am using [unison file syncing software](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ebcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#speeding) and I am aware of the config that ignores syncing files with specific regex or name. But is there a way to block syncing of large files e.g. larger than 10 MB?

```
ignore = Name *.swp
ignore = Path */env
ignore = Path */build
```

I have a slow internet speed at my place, and don't want to sync large files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

from page you linked

changelog

> Added a maxsizethreshold option, which prevents the transfer of files larger than the size specified (in Kb).

usage in command line :

```
-maxsizethreshold n prevent transfer of files bigger than this (if >=0, in Kb)
```